# User defined matrix of chars

Tags: c++

From user input such as:

```
>~d
alg
^%r
```

what would be the best way to create a square char matrix with each of the entered values assigned to the corresponding element? e.g. in this case charArray[0][0] would be '>' and charArray[2][1] would be '%' etc.

I tried the following using getchar(); however, I was having all kinds of problems with the '\n' that was left behind and figured there is probably an entirely different way of effecting this that was much better.

```
char matrix[MAX][MAX];
char c;
int matSize;

std::cin >> matSize;

for (int i = 0; i < matSize; ++i)
    {
        int j = 0;

        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
        {
            matrix[i][j] = c;
            ++j;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using C++, why not use std::cin and std::string to read a hole line. Probably not the best option, but it works.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matSize; ++i)
{
    std::cin >> in;
    if (in.length() < matSize)
    {
        printf("Wrong length\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < matSize; j++)
    matrix[i][j] = in[j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every `matrix[i]` is a char array with a fixed size you can easily use [`std::istream::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>

#define MAX 10

int main()
{
    char matrix[MAX][MAX];
    char c;
    int matSize;

    std::cin >> matSize;
    std::cin >> c; // don't forget to extract the first '\n'

    if(matSize > MAX){ // prevent segmentation faults / buffer overflows
        std::cerr << "Unsupported maximum matrix size" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < matSize; ++i){
        std::cin.getline(matrix[i],MAX); // extract a line into your matrix
    }


    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < matSize; ++i){
        std::cout << matrix[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```